# Probability of a number being a bound for roots

Tags: cv.complex-variables, probability-distributions

Consider the polynomial $p(z)=\sum_0^na_iz^k$ where $a_n=1$ and $a_k \sim N(0,1)$, $k=0,1,2,\dotsc,n-1.$
What is the probability that 2 will be a bound of the roots of the polynomial? How can we find the asymptotic probability for the same? I did a simulation for a polynomial of this type of degree 5 and I found im almost 91% of the cases, the roots lie within $|z| \leq 2$. However,I do not know how to go about it anlytically. Also, kindly reference the relevant literature, if any, about these kinds of problems about the random polynomials of the above-mentioned type. I would be  delighted and highly obliged for any help/hints/references.

Comment: You mean 2 being an upper bound for the absolute values of the complex roots?

Comment: yes ,of course!

Comment: i mean 2 being the bound for the absolute value of all roots

Comment: If you apply the Gershgorin circle theorem to the transpose of the companion matrix of $p$ then a lower bound for this probability can be obtained: it reduces to the probability that $\mathbb{P}(1 - a_{n-1} \leq 2 \text{ and } -1 - a_{n-1} \geq -2)$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(|a_{n-1}| \leq 1)$. However, this works out as about 60%, so far from optimal.

Comment: It is the same as to ask what is the probability that the random function $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}a_k z^k$ has no root in the unit disk. The only (obvious) thing I can say is that it is some value between $0$ and $1$ and we can get some reasonable lower and upper bounds for it, but I doubt the exact value can be given by any decent expression, though I'll be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: @DavidHughes Erm... It looks to me that other coefficients should play some role too, so I don't quite understand the part after "it reduces to...".

Comment: @fedja ,could you kindly explain why they are the same?i am sorry I did not get it

Comment: @AgnostMystic Divide by $z^n$, consider the result as a function of $1/z$ and rescale from the disk of radius $1/2$ to the unit disk. You'll get a partial sum of this series, and that is what you actually asked about for finite $n$, but since the series converges at the speed of a geometric progression a.s., passing to the limit as $n\to\infty$ is not a big problem either and the convergence of the corresponding probabilities is fairly quick too.

Comment: @fedja Sorry, I meant in the context of obtaining a lower bound. The Gershgorin domains for each row except the last one of the transpose of the companion matrix are disks of radius 1 around 0. So any root lying in those disks satisfies the condition, hence it is only the disk around $a_{n-1}$ that needs to lie inside the disk of radius 2 around 0 for the bound to hold, by Gershgorin.

Comment: @DavidHughes Ah, I see. You misinterpreted the problem then: the question was what is the probability that *all* roots are in that disk, not just that there is one root there :-)

Comment: @AgnostMystic BTW, while we are at it, when you are saying $N(0,1)$, which one do you mean: real or complex one? :-)

Comment: @fedja my understanding is that the question asked for the probability that all roots lie inside the disk of radius 2 about 0. Gershgorin gives a set in which all roots must lie and my argument gave the probability this set was contained in the disk of radius 2 about 0.

Comment: @DavidHughes Then, apparently, I misunderstand you somewhere. It seems to me that you claimed that you could create a sufficient condition for *all roots* to lie in the disk of radius $2$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ *alone* and I claim that if $|a_0|>2^n$, then no matter what $a_{n-1}$ you choose, there will be a root outside. What am I confused about?

Comment: @DavidHughes The last Gershgorin disc should have radius $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \abs{a_i}$ so the condition should be $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \abs{a_i}\leq 2$

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your setting, with $a_n=1$ (and i.i.d. $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$?), but closely related settings were considered e.g. by [Götze and Zaporozhets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51889453_On_the_Distribution_of_Complex_Roots_of_Random_Polynomials_withHeavy-tailed_Coefficients) and [Ibragimov and Zaporozhets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/48209208_On_Distribution_of_Zeros_of_Random_Polynomials_in_Complex_Plane). See also further references there.

In particular, in the paper by Götze and Zaporozhets we find the following:

> Shparo and Shur [9] showed that under quite general assumptions the roots [...]
> concentrate near the unit circle as $n$ tends to $\infty$ with asymptotically uniform distribution of the argument.

> Ibragimov and Zaporozhets [4] improved this result

> Shepp and Vanderbei [8] considered real-valued standard Gaussian coefficients

> Ibragimov and Zeitouni [3] extended this relation to the case of
> arbitrary i.i.d. coefficients from the domain of attraction of an $\alpha$-stable law

Even though your setting is a bit different, I am sure that arguments in the mentioned papers can be adapted to your situation.

Comment: thank you for the references.Since my result is weaker in its claims and I do not have a strong background in random polynomials ,could you kindly suggest some approach  or give me some hints

Comment: @AgnostMystic : I suggest you read the proof of Theorem 1 by Götze and Zaporozhets. It is elementary and only about 3.5 pages in length, including the auxiliary lemmas. I think it should be rather easy to adapt that proof to your situation. However, such an adaptation will likely be too long for a MathOverflow answer. If you have difficulties reading that proof, please let me know.

Comment: thank you @losif Pinnelis ,i will definitely go through it and try to understand it

Comment: I found that the papers deal with the asymptotic cases when n is very large and my problem is about a certain number c
being a bound for finite degree polynomials ,which requires to compute the probability that all roots lie within |z|≤c
 and I could not find any similar problem in the literature.Or may be I am wrong ,may be their technique can  be adapted to this problem.I would be highly obliged for just some hints